# Subtract two dates in PHP / Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I've searched but could not find the solution for my case.

One date is recorded at MYSQL,
for example it returns: `2013-10-18 15:42:06` (which format is this ?)

So I need to get the `current date` (including hours, minutes and seconds).

Then, subtract the `MYSQL date - CURRENT date`.

The result, i'll set as an jQuery countdown.

Thanks!

Comment: Regarding your format question: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS". See [MariaDB Knowledgebase](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/datetime/) or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

`$seconds_remaining = strtotime('2013-10-18 15:42:06') - time();`

Although if you happen to know what timezone the MySQL time corresponds to, then you should append that to the argument passed to `strtotime()`, e.g., `'2013-10-18 15:42:06 GMT'`